# Same font in math mode decimal comma?

Tags: siunitx, punctuation, mathspec, icomma

I want to use comma (,) as decimal separator. The problem is that it is typeset with wrong font (Computer Modern, I suppose), not with the normal font defined using mathspec package. I have tried icomma package and siunitx package but they don't affect the font.

Here is a minimal code to try. The last two "1,5" examples have wrong comma font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){DejaVu Serif}

\begin{document}

1,5

\( 1,5 \)

\( \num{1,5} \)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This here should work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){DejaVu Serif}


\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`,}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

1,5

\( 1,5\)

\( \num{1,5} \)

\(1, 5\) %larger space in lists
\end{document}
```

[image]